# "There's nothing here yet" after deploying Java Web App on Azure

Tags: java, azure, jetty, azure-web-app-service, javalite

I have a web app I want to deploy on Azure. I followed the recommended instructions and deployed my app, and according to the Azure portal, everything is working just fine. However, when I visit the base URL my app should reside in, I see a page that says the following:

> This Java based web application has been successfully created
>
> There's nothing here yet, but Microsoft Azure makes it simple to
>   publish content with GIT and FTP

Also when I visit any one of the endpoints (in this case, the /live endpoint) my app should have, I always see a page with the following message:

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /live. Reason:
>
> Not Found
>
> Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.13.v20161014

When I look at the directories on the machine, everything seems to be in place. All my files are inside `wwwroot`. However, there's another directory named `webapp` under `wwwroot` and inside it is another directory named `ROOT` with two files: `index.jsp` and `background.png`. `index.jsp` is the page that shows the aforementioned "There's nothing here yet" message.

I'm using Bitbucket as my source control provider and I use jetty to run my web app. I'm also using [javalite](http://javalite.io/) as the library to manage my server and different endpoints.

Comment: can you successfully deploy and  run your app locally on Jetty or Tomcat?

Comment: @ipolevoy yes, everything runs smoothly when I run jetty locally. In fact I deployed this on a remote virtual machine with Capistrano and it works smoothly there as well. Now I want to deploy it using Azure for the sake of scalability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to put your stuff under `wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/`, or package as `ROOT.war` and drop that under `wwwroot/webapps` - it will get picked up and extracted automagically:

```
wwwroot
 └── webapps
        └── ROOT
            ├── about.jsp
            ├── Content
            │   ├── favicon.ico
            │   └── Site.css
            ├── Images
            │   ├── banner_coffee.png
            ├── index.jsp
            ├── META-INF
            │   ├── context.xml
            │   └── MANIFEST.MF
            ├── orderconfirmation.jsp
            ├── placeorder.jsp
            ├── Scripts
            │   ├── jquery-1.7.1.min.js
            └── WEB-INF
                ├── classes
                ├── lib
                ├── log4j.properties
                └── web.xml
```

From https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-web-java-get-started:

> The main thing in the repo is a `webapps` folder with `ROOT.war`. The **Tomcat/Jetty server in App Service will look inside this folder for web apps to host.**
>
> `ROOT.war` represents the default web app (at the site root). Any WAR file that's otherwise named represents a web app accessbile at `~/<WARfilename>`.

#### Clearing things up

- If your application sits in `wwwroot/webapps/CoffeeShop/`, then you'll access it at `http://{site}.azurewebsites.net/CoffeeShop/`.
- If your application sits in `wwwroot/webapps/ROOT/`, then you'll access it at `http://{site}.azurewebsites.net/`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try doing this and let you know the results.